# Cookies from Apache to Android App

Tags: android, tomcat, cookies

**What i know is I am doing it WRONG; What i don't know is how to do it right. 
Here is a little code for the Apache servlet.**

@Override

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("application/Cookie");// May be wrong
Cookie c = new Cookie("cookie", "CookieS i LOVE");
c.setMaxAge(60*60);response.addCookie(c);
      }
For Android app i have this code to get the cookie sent from the that servlet.
Now i want to store that cookie on my android device. and then retrieve it for
another activities.



{....}
    public void onClick(View v) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://********:8080/***/servlet");
    Cookie c = (Cookie) CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL;
    try {
    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpget);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    List<Cookie> cookies =  ((AbstractHttpClient)client).getCookieStore()
    .getCookies();          
    String mycookie = cookies.toString();
    Toast.makeText(Cookies.this, mycookie, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    }           
    Thank You for your help.
```

Comment: `and then retrieve it for another activities` means to the same application but different activities or different applicaitons?

Comment: Yeah it is log in, so first screen is for signup thing, and the rest screens are for business purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store cookies:

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = null;
private SharedPreferences pref = null;

...
mEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();

...

mCookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

if (mCookies.isEmpty()) {
  Log.d("test_runner", "Cookies: None");
}
 else {
 for (int i = 0; i < mCookies.size(); i++) {
   mEditor.putString("Cookies_" + i, mCookies.get(i).toString() );
 }
    mEditor.commit();
}
```

And now in other activity call them like:

```
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String cookies =pref.getString("Cookies_0", "");

....
```

*As a side note*

I would use Gson library to convert Cookies list to string and store in preferences only one value that represents all cookies.

After, on extract, convert with Gson back from String to List

Comment: Thank You Maxim Shoustin, What if i wanna use CookieStore to store those cookies and get them by CookieManager, is this possible.

Comment: If you use the same application, for sure you can use instance of `CookieManager`. But bear in mind after Activity close, all info reset. So you can put into Service to make it run in background or use my way.